# Jmeter On Demand triggering of any particular API during a test

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario where there is one particular API generates tokens in the below manner. Say it is generating 20 tokens now. I am passing all those token values into next 20 subsequent requests.

{

"data" : {
"requestTokens" : [ "9FDE794DD00E4A09122343BDCAF214E9", "616C5DFFC1234516A925824AEA6EFE9F", "7A8C507EC1DF4AD88E0912345E1DB409", "763C32CF67899946B6BC946949BD1344", "3C143F2FC25E495012345500E0F343DF", "3FD78335C763420B1234574061D9417F", "C43C368A1E612345AB17D2BA2693BEAF", "56E8FA9036D3486123451DE3237004DC", "5867B8E399FB4E12345626337D0E143C", "D06B30BDEAFC4A7D8618BF67712345DB", "F795258D390D4812345EB62C83BEFC58", "F0829D861234560392DE432E121B3CD4", "C8B9D5E6BE6A465FB91B0123459FBA9A", "4169D93D97204123457BA5A98C914D27", "784809E5BCBF4F123459D7D848AD67CE", "D0BFDCDC13994C0123455B2B110C35F9", "4F59619BBEDE4FE812345EA14C5E785", "E3942AE182214605BE91234595D95C18", "2005C506659C425EAD2022446123459B", "FE716E2A13A74C759C12345AED5AD54C" ]
}
}

So this value 20 is dynamic. For now as work around I am capturing this 20 values as an array using JSON extractor and passing those values. But tomorrow if this value is changed to 10 my script will Fail. Because it generates 10 tokens and I am out of tokens after tenth request. Hence on demand we have to trigger that particular API which generates tokens and pass it to the subsequent requests. Is there some approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both extraction and building the next request body can be done in [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language

I cannot provide a code snippet because you didn't share the response data, in the meantime you can get familiarized with the following materials:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your response. Followed the links and and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) that will be configured something like:

- Names of created variables = `tokens`
- JSON Path Expressions = `$.data.requestTokens[*]`
- Match No. = `-1`

This will grab all your tokens into variables named `tokens_1`, `tokens_2`, `tokens_3`, and so on. However many of them there are.

Next you create a [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) that will be configured something like:

- Input variable prefix = `tokens`
- Output variable = `token`

This will loop over all the tokens that were extracted in the previous step. You add your "subsequent" step(s) to this controller. You can refer to the loop variable as `${token}` in the steps inside this loop.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @Tester_Local No problem. Just FYI: A "thank you" is done by an upvote around here. ;)